# What is causing "Could not resolve CoreCLR path" when referencing a Console App from another Console App?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-6.0

I'm trying to build a console application, A, into another console application, B (an NUnit testing project). B references A by a ProjectReference.

When running A, it works fine. All is also fine when I run B without referencing A. However, I'm met with the aforementioned error when B references A. Why? And how can I fix it?

Some similar questions I've found do not fix the issue.

- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/5779 - My runtimeconfig is as follows:

```json
{
    "runtimeOptions": {
        "tfm" : "net6.0",
        "framework" : {
            "name" : "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
            "version" : "6.0.12"
        }
    }
}
```

- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/5844 - Not related
- https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4825 - Not fully related

Note that setting `COREHOST_TRACE` to 1 only provides the same error (directly after culture dependency errors/logs)

```bash
Could not resolve CoreCLR path. For more details, enable tracing by setting COREHOST_TRACE environment variable to 1
```

- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/5916 - `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` do not fix the issue.
- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/5672 - Fix is irrelevant.
- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/could-not-resolve-coreclr-path-error/50916 - I'm using win-x86, no changes there.
- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/4870 - Not using Ubuntu, seems irrelevant.
- As for https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/4870#issuecomment-542991656;

I can confirm that the necessary package dependencies and JSON files are present in the output directory of B. This is what actually fixed a preceding error, relating to `hostpolicy.dll`.

**Update:** It seems that this issue is resolved in .NET 7 (tested with two minimal console applications). In cases of absolute desperation, a shared library which is referenced instead may be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your post was helpful (thank you).

I was hitting the same issue and found that in my case it was because the project had the runtime identifier (RID) set to linux but I was developing in windows.

By updating the RID to be win-x64 I was able to get around the issue.

TL;DR: double check your RID(s) and that your local machine matches expectations in the csproj file. It may just be a matter of updating the RID.

e.g.:

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

Should be updated to:

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```